# updating application on AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have few questions regarding AWS elastic beanstalk. My upcoming mobile application has backend written in php and it uses mysql database.

I learnt that FTP is not possible with AWS elastic beanstalk. If I have to make changes to the any application, I have upload the entire applications once again.

My questions is: while uploading the application fresh, will there be downtime?  will it destroy the old database and create fresh one?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload a new version of the application using the console or you can use the CLI tools or the API.

You can avoid downtime of your application during deployments by increasing the minimum number of instances > 1 and then you can do a rolling deployment (with batch size < number of instances). You can choose either a time based or health based rolling deployment. This will ensure that the code is deployed only to a subset of the instances at any given point of time.

You can read about rolling deployments here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.rollingupdates.html